# How to make wp cron job not fire immediately?

Tags: cron, wp-cron

I'm scheduling a job in wp cron:

```
add_action('my_cron_hook', 'my_cron_action');
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'interval1', 'my_cron_hook' ); 

function my_cron_action(){
    //do something
}
```

The variable interval1 is set by the admin in another part of the code.
Also, there is a switch that lets the admin *enable* or *disable* the wp crop job.

**My problem is this:**
my_cron_action is executed as soon as it is scheduled
(this means, as soon as the admin enables the cron job from the backend).

**What i want to do is this:**
if we suppose that the time that the admin enabled the job is **T**,
i want the job to be run at **T+interval1** for the first time, and *not at T*.

The next thing i want after this is done, is to create a button "Execute job now" that will run the job as soon as it's clicked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in [wp_schedule_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) first parameter is `$timestamp` - the first time that you want the event to occur. So just add interval to $timestamp. I think it should be like

```
wp_schedule_event( time() + $delay, 'interval1', 'my_cron_hook' );
```

And set `$delay` as miliseconds before hook starts.